# abstract class and Template Method pattern and HttpServlet

Tags: java, servlets, design-patterns, abstract-class, template-method-pattern

There is no any abstract methods in the `HttpServlet` which is declared abstract class with key word abstract.  `doGet` and others are not abstract methods. So why `HttpServlet` is declared as abstract class without any abstract class?

Is the `HttpServlet` an example of template method pattern?

What's the template pattern and template method pattern. What's the differences?

Comment: Via documentation: "Provides an abstract class to be subclassed to create an HTTP servlet suitable for a Web site.".  It is abstracted because they want to force you to extend it with your own functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpServlet` is declared as abstract because you are meant to subclass it.  By itself, it would not provide much useful behavior, so you should extend the class and define your own behavior for one or more of the methods (most commonly, either `doGet` or `doPost`).

Yes, `HttpServlet` is an example of the template method pattern.  The `doXXX` methods in `HttpServlet` are called from the `service` method.  In other words, we have a template method (`service`) deferring some of its processing to individual methods defined in subclasses.  These methods are selected at compile time, so this is an example of the template method pattern.

See also:

- [Abstract Methods and Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)
- [Where should we use Template Method - pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553856/where-should-we-use-template-method-pattern)
- [Why should I declare a class as an abstract class?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/96947/why-should-i-declare-a-class-as-an-abstract-class)