# What pattern to use when reusing functions

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, callback

So I wanted to reuse some functionalities like the `try catch` and some other common functionalities used by  my application. I was wondering if this approach is ok. Or if there is any other approach that would be great. I want to learn the different ways on how I can implement this.

This is a callback function that services will use.

```
 public interface ClientOperation <T>{
      T doAction(SomeObject someObject);
    }
```

And this is the interface which will execute the callback function of `ClientOperation`

```
 public interface Executor {

    <T> T doTask(ClientOperation<T> operation);
    }
```

The implementation class of `Executor`

```
    public class ExecutorImpl implements Executor {



    public <T> T doTask(ClientOperation<T> operation) {
        T response = null;
        /*
            DO SOMETHING FIRST - USED BY ALL CLASSES
        */

        try {
            response = operation.doAction(someObject);
        } catch (SomeException e) {
            /*
                DO SOME SERIOUS STUFF
            */

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
            throw new SystemException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

A service that does something and implements the callback function

```
public void addSomething(final Secret secret)
            throws UnauthorizedActionException, InvalidSecretKeyException {

            executorService.doTask(new ClientOperation<Response>() {
                public Response doAction(SomeObject someObject) {

                //DO STUFF ON THIS
                    return template.write(secret.getPath(),
                            secret.getSecretValue());

                }
            });


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to learn the different ways on how I can implement this.

Your approach seems perfectly fine. I would take it one step further and make the input (i.e `SomeObject`) generic as well so that `ClientOperation` can work with different input types.

```
public interface ClientOperation <T,S>{
      T doAction(S someObject);
}
```

An alternate approach would be to use the [Template Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553856/where-should-we-use-template-method-pattern) pattern where `ClientOperation` is converted to an `abstract` class with  an `abstract` `doAction` method and a concrete `final` `doTask` method that calls `doAction` in a `try-catch` block. Subclasses provide the implementation for the `doAction` method. A drawback of this approach would be that you can't extend from any other class.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the feedback. I also think that template method also limit the concrete subclasses to 1 implementation method.